# Cocoa App - Current way to make a start at login item

Tags: xcode, cocoa, helper, autostart

I'm currently writing an application which includes a helper app that can to be startet at login at the users request.

Many apps are using the LSShareFileList method which is deprecated.
Another way would be the System Management Framework using SMLoginItemSetEnabled which won't give the user the ability to see the login item in the "Startup Items" list in the system preferences.

The last option i've found is using a LaunchAgent to realize this which also wouldn't create a entry in the "Startup Items" list for the user.

Is there currently no (official supported) way to realize a "Login at startup" method inside the app which will create a Login Item at the users system preferences?

Thanks!